# linux dlopen: can a library be "notified" when it is loaded?

Tags: linux, dlopen, shared-libraries

Is there a way for a shared library to be "notified" when it is loaded?

In other words, let's say I use *dlopen* on a shared library, is there a function that is automatically called (if present) on the shared library (e.g. main?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Libraries should export initialization
>   and cleanup routines using the gcc
>   __attribute__((constructor)) and __attribute__((destructor)) function attributes. See the gcc info pages for
>   information on these. Constructor
>   routines are executed before dlopen
>   returns (or before main() is started
>   if the library is loaded at load
>   time). Destructor routines are
>   executed before dlclose returns (or
>   after exit() or completion of main()
>   if the library is loaded at load
>   time). The C prototypes for these
>   functions are:

```
 void __attribute__ ((constructor))  my_init(void);  
 void __attribute__  ((destructor)) my_fini(void);
```

Taken from http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/index.html

THat is, you just tack on  __attribute__ ((constructor))  to the functions you want to be called when the shared library is loaded. The above docuemtn also notes that the older _ini and _fini functions are considered obsolete.

Comment: Note: highly non-portable.

Answer (score 17):

Yes. When a library is opened, all static construction takes place... so, if you use C++, you can do:

```
// mylibrary.cpp
namespace
{
    class dynamic_library_load_unload_handler
    {
         public:
              dynamic_library_load_unload_handler(){
                    // Code to execute when the library is loaded
              }
              ~dynamic_library_load_unload_handler(){
                    // Code to execute when the library is unloaded
              }
    } dynamic_library_load_unload_handler_hook;
}
```

Unlike the `__attribute__ ((constructor))` solutions given, this will be portable. Note, though, that if you have multiple objects like this, there is no guarantee with respect to the construction/destruction order.

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to get argc and argv in the ctor? Linux (ELF) specific solution: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2002-10/msg01296.html

Comment: @TrueY, I'm not familiar with a portable solution, but let me know if you find one. That being said, from an API standpoint, I would suggest that libraries let the applications determine what commandline switches configure what... rather than attempt to read argc/argv... consider providing utility routines that can load configuration from a file and/or from the commandline that libraries can optionally use (but also provide direct methods for the application to configure the library's behavior).

Comment: Interesting. And in plain C you could only have a constructor this way (global variable initialized by a function call), since there's no notion of "static deinitialization".

Answer (score 0):

At least on Linux, and probably on at least some other Unix systems, if the library is dynamically opened a global function named `_init`, if it exists, will be called by the dynamic linker.

Comment: ... what is the prototype for this _init function?

Comment: @Jack: just found out through http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html#INIT-AND-CLEANUP that the _init and _fini special functions are marked as OBSOLETE/DANGEROUS...