# Programming in Unix: Sharing libraries with libraries

Tags: c, unix, shared-libraries

Working in C, on top of unix, I am loading and using a shared library somewhat as follows:

```
...

handle = dlopen("nameOfLib");

...

libInit();

...

libGoToState1();


libGoToState2();


....

libTerminate();

...

dlclose(handle);

...
```

What I would like is for my application to admit 'plugins' which take the form of dynamically loadable libraries that adhere to a given API.

The tricky part is that I want to load a plugin after calling `libInit()` and I want the plugin to be able to call `libGoToSomeOtherState()`,  altering the state of the library, but making use of the same 'session' as the application that loaded it.

Any thoughts on how I need to go about coding this are appreciated.

Specifically, what needs to go into the .c files for the plugin and the main program in order for them to share a library instance, state and all?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602398/linux-dlopen-can-a-library-be-notified-when-it-is-loaded

Comment: You'll need "-Wl,--export-dynamic" option when linking the executable if you want dynamic library call back into the exe itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to export an interface to be used by a plugin is to either put that interface itself into a shared library that the plugin links to, or else pass the plugin a structure of function pointers (in libInit(), presumably) that it then uses to do its work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but an article on how to create simple plugins for C programs was posted on reddit a few days ago:

http://thisxorthat.blogspot.com/2010/01/choose-indecision-simple-plugins-in-c.html

Answer (score 1):

The plugin can call `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "libGoToSomeOtherState")` to obtain the address of the function it wants to call, or you can directly pass that function pointer to the plugin's init routine (perhaps within a table of such function pointers).

Answer (score 0):

As a brief hint I'd suggest using callbacks: either passing the library handle to the plugin, or use function pointers inside the plugin to call the original library functions.